# Concurrent Modification Exception Writing to Realm in onPostExecute method - Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, realm, concurrentmodification

I am using Realm as my Database. And while inserting/updating the data I am getting the following error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: uk.org.humanfocus.hfi, PID: 6430
 java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)
  at org.json.JSONArray.writeTo(JSONArray.java:612)
  at org.json.JSONStringer.value(JSONStringer.java:233)
  at org.json.JSONObject.writeTo(JSONObject.java:720)
  at org.json.JSONObject.toString(JSONObject.java:689)
  at uk.org.humanfocus.hfi.DriverBehavior.DriverBehaviorMap$InsertCarProbeData.onPostExecute(DriverBehaviorMap.java:252)
  at uk.org.humanfocus.hfi.DriverBehavior.DriverBehaviorMap$InsertCarProbeData.onPostExecute(DriverBehaviorMap.java:229)
  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
  at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Unlike others I am not doing it in the for loop, **instead I am doing it in the onPostExecute method of AsyncTask** which is called from location changed listener. Neither is it being used somewhere else.

```
private class InsertCarProbeData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    Location location;

    public InsertCarProbeData(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            addObjectToJSONArray(location);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        realm.beginTransaction();
        trip.json = tripJSON.toString();
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }
}
```

And this AsyncTask is being called from here

```
new InsertCarProbeData(location).execute();
```

Comment: Dear Downvoter, In case of down votes please comment the reason so I can avoid my mistake in future.

Comment: Without knowladge about addObjectToJSONArray I bet that `tripJSON.toString()` is called at the same time as `addObjectToJSONArray(location);` (which on 99% modyfing `tripJSON`)

Comment: And about downvote: I bet that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may help ... and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Selvin addObjectToJSONArray(location); is called from doInBackground and tripJSON.toString() is called from onPostExecute. Arent it supposed to be called after the change has taken place?

Comment: What version of Realm are you using?

Comment: *Arent it supposed to be called after the change has taken place?* Yes ... and?  It is obvious ... you just create and execute new async task  when old one was in "`onPostExecute` state" ... it's multithreading ...

Comment: @EpicPandaForce 2.0.2
It seems that if I do it in background thread, it may fix this issue

Comment: **BTW** the downvotes are because obviously the offending line is `tripJSON.toString();`, but where `tripJSON` is initialized is unknown, and so is `addObjectToJSONArray`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is several problens in your code:

1) you store all values inside JSONArray, that means, it will attempt to wtite ALL PREVIOUS values too. When array grow large, new data arraive while old values is still bein processed - that is reason of error

2) .onPostExecute() method is executed on main thread, so by doing so, you have no benefit of AsyncTask.

3) AsyncTask is obsolete and is shares the same thread pool (with the same proirity, as main thread)

There is similar answer, look into it:  [Writing realm from service class causing UI block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40717687/writing-realm-from-service-class-causing-ui-block)

Comment: As you said AsyncTask is obsolete, what should be used instead?

Comment: rxJava library, see link in the answer

Comment: *AsyncTask is obsolete* ... **no, it is not**